# Error reading txt file c++

Tags: c++, stream

I have this code that suppose to read a txt file.
But for some reason i am always getting `*File not found` that means that `fileIn.fail()` failed...

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <stdio.h>


using namespace std;

int main ()
{
    string fileName;
    ifstream fileIn;
    bool x;

    cout << "enter file name \n";
    cin  >> fileName;

    fileIn.open(fileName);

    if(fileIn.fail())
    {
        cerr << "* File not found";
        return true;
    }
```

the file located in the same folder as my main.cpp file and named input.txt. I have tried to set the fileName hard coded but this also didn't work.
What is wrong with my code?

here is the project:

[image]

Comment: Just because the can not be opened, doesn't mean that it can't be found, there may be other errors as well. However, when you run your program, in which folder are you in relation to the folder where the executable file (and the file you want to read)? Are you in the same folder? In another folder?

Comment: I am using xcode (for the first time) so I am not sure where it puts the exe files... where do I need to look for them?

Comment: Always a problem with first time users, using an IDE ;-)

Comment: To find the output location in XCode, try opening the solution tree under "Products".  Right click "question2" and then Show in Finder.

Comment: What is the value of errno? eg:  cerr << "* File not found: " << errno;

Comment: Test this with an absolute path. If that fail its most likely permissions.

Comment: with the full path it worked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a checklist:

1. Do you have permissions to read/access the file?
2. Are you the owner of the file?(Linux)
3. Are you giving the correct path, relative or absolute from the executable?

If the answer to any of these is a no, then that is where the problem lies, not just "file not found" error.

--EDIT--

@VladIoffe the executable I see there, is `qustion2` and the relative path you have to give is `../input.txt` and not input.txt

Comment: I am using mac, and I am not sure where it puts the exe files. any help with that?

Comment: well, show me your directory structure, maybe a screenshot and I will tell you where it is. @VladIoffe

Comment: I have added a screenshot

Comment: @VladIoffe the executable I see there, is `quiston2` and the relative path you have to give is `../input.txt` and not `input.txt`

Comment: yes, I saw it now when I tried to move the input file. still file not found.

Comment: I also set permission to read and write (recursively for all the project)

Comment: @VladIoffe open a terminal, navigate to the project's folder, execute your executable from the terminal, and then see the output. Let me know as soon as you do it.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/40847/discussion-between-vlad-ioffe-and-aniket)

Answer (score 0):

You should use absolute path to the fileName.

Answer (score 0):

Absoulut path will always works. But I hate full path I prefer relative path for a simple reason: code is more portable.
If you run your program with input.txt in the same path of executable it will work. But when you use an IDE you must set the current directory in the IDE settings.